# R In Rstudio Server renv not keep activated

Tags: r, rstudio-server, renv

The question is very important for us.
We installed renv in our server's Rstudio Server. And propose to use it for every project. In order to see if that works for the team, I made the first attempt.
Although the Server keeps on running(we didn't terminate R session if we leave work every day.) but next day when I come back to work, I often see the renv is not activated any more. (e.g. When I use renv::hydrate() it tells me the renv is not yet activated in this project, so the status is different from yesterday).

I don't want this because,if I want to use renv I need to activate it every time,it will restart the whole r session,it took time and may lead to some other unexpected result or status.

I guess the reason:
1 Although we didn't manually terminate Rstudio Server, it actually restarted during standby at night.
2 Some unknown process stopped renv from activated status.

Anyone knows the solution or reason is welcomed.

Comment: I'm not quite following your description of the problem. renv is intended to be used separately for each project, so I would expect to have to call `renv::init()` the first time you create any new project, and then anytime you open that project renv will be active. At least that's always been my experience using both renv both locally and on Posit Workbench.

Comment: @joran locally,yes, the team will use renv so that each project could has its own version of package without break other's package env. But on Rstudio server the renv is not always activated as locally, that's why I pose this question.

Comment: Well, I still don't understand your description of the problem, because renv isn't a process or program that "runs" on your computer, either locally or remotely. It's just a set of files that either are, or are not present in a project directory with a setting in one of the files that says whether it is active. So starting/stopping the server won't have any impact on renv at all. The only way the renv settings would change is if one of the users is altering the renv files.

Comment: @joran yeah,when you init renv, it should print you something like "renv x.x.x loaded", I guess that is something related to the activation of the renv system, or like when you play games you load the saves, then you can use all commends related to renv, locally it is always kept loaded(even if you restart r session, it will automatically reloaded, but in rstudio serve, it is not the case, at least I can't use renv next time I log into the server.)

Comment: If the renv related files are already there? yes, but the renv is not activated, how did I know it is not activated? because when I use method like renv::hydrate it reminds me renv is not activated, then I activated it, then it restart my r session(it takes 10 mins), and then I could use renv's method, but next time when I leave and come next day and  connect to rstudio server, it no activated again, is that clear?

Comment: Again, the only way that makes any sense to me is if somehow all the renv files (or some specific ones that are critical to renv) in the project were deleted or altered between uses. You shouldn't have to do anything to "keep renv activated". Once the files are there after calling renv:init(), you shouldn't need to do anything. The `renv::deactivate()` function typically will only remove a few lines from the project .RProfile file. Is someone overwriting or altering project .RProfile files between sessions?

Comment: I will check if any renv related file is updated everytime, and if that is not the case, then there may be something or process stopped when the rstudio server disconnected. As for the issue, I can reproduce everyday for 2 months, it must has something to support the mechanism, I am not some one who will spend time post something never happen here.

Comment: How exactly did you convert your existing(?) project to use renv?

Comment: @margusl I didn't convert it, I start a brand new project with renv selected, I don't know if I catch what you mean here. Let me know if you need any info to help you locate and solve this.

Comment: `renv` is 'project' specific. When you come back the next day, is the project actually still active? As others have pointed out, renv is not a process that is running but simply a collection of files, which usually stay in the project directory.

Comment: @Niklas,interesting, what do you mean that "is the project still active?", so when I return to the rstudio server the next day, I am in another project? Actually there is a thing I was wondering for a long time, how did rstudio know when I open it, which project should it open and go into?

Comment: I don't know if it works but what you said make sense to me. @Niklas

Comment: You can see which project is active in the top right corner of RStudio. RStudio server stores information about the active session (mainly which project it uses) in the cache see for example this https://support.posit.co/hc/en-us/articles/218730228-Resetting-a-user-s-state-on-Posit-RStudio-Workbench-RStudio-Server

Answer (score 0):

As @Niklas pointed out in the comments, Renv is a collection of files.
Renv works with a lockfile to snapshot() and status() your list of packages and also restore() it if needed. ([Source](https://rstudio.github.io/renv/))

This file is in use almost all the time. The description of your problem suggests to me that your project is saved in a cloud service such as OneDrive or Dropbox. The synchronisation of this file will fail all the time, but is probably being pushed through at midnight. Changing the lockfile in the source while the project is still running, may cause problems.

The solution would be to save your project not in a cloud location. (This is highly recommended as Git does not work well with OneDrive or Dropbox anyway and Git is a better way of tracking changes in code and sharing code). Otherwise, exclude your lockfile from the synchronisation step in your cloud app. (This is easier)